# Create document on update only if condition is met mongodb

Tags: mongodb, upsert

Please see mongo query below. 
I want to be able to update a document if it meets the conditions.
I want to create a new document if x or y arent met but i dont want to create a new document if x and y are met but z has a value

```
 collection.update({ x : 1, y : 2, z : {$exists : false} }, {field_to_update : update}, { upsert :true })
```

Comment: an update takes another field - what is it that you want to do to the document with x:1, y:2 and z:3 if one exists?

Comment: i want to update it. I did not include the update object but it is assumed.

Comment: I see you found the answer yourself - query on x:1,y:2,z:3 (not exists, but original condition that you had before you edited) and set {upsert:true} along with having a unique index on { x:1, y:1 } - this will allow you to upsert the document only if those x, y values don't already exist (presumably with different z value since it didn't match).

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to create a unique compound index on the first two fields. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a "possible" way to do this, but you have to be very careful about what you are even considering here. Consider the following initial documents:

```js
{ "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "z" : 4, "a" : 2 }
{ "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "a" : 2 }
{ "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "z" : 5, "a" : 4 }
{ "x" : 4, "y" : 2, "a": 1 }
```

Your basic conditions say that you want to match on "x" and "y" but only insert a new document  if there is not a match on "z" for any value. Presumably though if "x" and "y" do not match then you want to insert a new document.

The main consideration here is "which" document do you want to update? There may be as shown above multiple matches to this condition, which would ideally match two of the documents here and not the document that has `{ "x": 1, "y": 2 }` but no value for "z". If you are okay with that as a logic principle then the following might be of use:

```js
db.test.update(
    { 
        "x": 1, 
        "y": 2, 
        "z": { "$exists": true },
    }, 
    { 
        "$set": { "a": 3 }, 
        "$setOnInsert": { "z": 3 }
    },
    { 
        "multi": true, 
        "upsert": true
    }
)
```

The important part here is the use of the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator since you don't want to modify anything that simply didn't have anything for "z" at all, you could additionally constrain that to numeric types if needed but the main point is missing the document you do not want to update.

Since you are not specifying a value of "z" to match on the query side, it is likely that you do have something you want when you "upsert", so include that in the [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) modifier as we show what happens when the conditions do not match:

```js
db.test.update(
    { 
        "x": 4, 
        "y": 2, 
        "z": { "$exists": true },
    }, 
    { 
        "$set": { "a": 3 }, 
        "$setOnInsert": { "z": 3 }
    },
    { 
        "multi": true, 
        "upsert": true
    }
)
```

So while there was a document there with the same values for "x" and "y" as given in the statement, it does not have any value for "z" and so a new document would be inserted by the "upsert" condition. The resulting documents from the two statements now look like this:

```js
{ "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "z" : 4, "a" : 3 }
{ "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "a" : 2 }
{ "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "z" : 5, "a" : 3 }
{ "x" : 4, "y" : 2, "a" : 1 }
{ "x" : 4, "y" : 2, "a" : 3, "z" : 3 }
```

As long as you can live with the consideration that "any value" for "z" can easily result in multiple documents being updated, then this is the way to handle the "upsert" conditions that you want.

Comment: No i dont think that works. I am actually using the third parameter as exists already. Maybe i should have been more explicit but i figured it all added up to the same thing. I want to update if x and y are met but not when z exists. I want to create a new document when x and y are not met and only when z does not exist. I do not want to create a new document when x and y are met but z exists.